# SQL Server NULL and DEFAULT column specifications

Tags: database-design, null, default, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a difference between declaring a column with just `Allow Nulls = Yes` as compared to declaring it with both `Default Value or Binding = NULL` AND `Allow Nulls = Yes`?

In particular I'm interested in if there is a difference with respect to JDBC and the wasNull method semantics. My impression was that `Allow Nulls = Yes` (without a DEFAULT spec) was sufficient to allow you to exclude the column from an INSERT clause and expect that the value of that field in the inserted row is assigned the SQL NULL value...

It has been suggested to me that wasNull misbehaves for specifically for an NVARCHAR field in my database that is retrieved from a result set using the getString method of the result set when I didn't have the DEFAULT specified explicitly as NULL...

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a column to have a default value of `NULL`, but it's a spectacularly pointless thing to do. All I'd expect it to achieve is to minutely slow down the insertion process (since it has to look up the default value). `Allow Nulls = Yes` should be sufficient.

I don't see how `wasNull` comes into this specifically, since, so far as I understand it, `wasNull` is used when consuming result sets, not when performing insert operations.

Comment: Actually, depending on the data type, declaring the column to have a default value of `NULL` may be exactly what needs to be done.

Comment: @Michael - have you got an example you're thinking of?

Comment: @Damien: See the link in my answer.

Comment: (Obviously, that should be depending on the data type *and the desired result*.)

Comment: @Michael - there's no mention of requiring a default to achieve a null. The fourth bullet point says "Is nullable. A null value is used." - which would indicate that you don't need to do anything else to that column.

Comment: @Damien: The way I read it was as a sequence of possibilities. Otherwise, what if you have, say, a nullable timestamp column? Or for that matter, a nullable column with a non-NULL default value. Clearly SQL Server can't pick a rule at random.

Comment: @Michael - they are ordered - but IDENTITY columns can't be nullable (so NULL is never valid), a non-NULL default isn't being discussed here, and you're not allowed a default constraint (of any value) against a timestamp column. So if you've got a nullable column that you want to default to null, you can rely on it reaching bullet number 4.

Answer (score 1):

Simply making the column allow nulls does not guarantee that it will have the value `NULL` if it is not provided in an `INSERT` statement's column list.

[Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) has the gory details under the *Arguments* heading. Look at `(column_list)`.